# A Negative binomial problem $P(X \ge 5)$ equals?

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions

> Consider a sequence of independent Bernoulli trials with the
> probability of success in each trial being $\dfrac{1}{3}$. Let $X$
> denote the number of trials required to get the second success. Then
> $P(X \ge 5)$ equals.
>
> $A=\dfrac{3}{7}$
>
> $B=\dfrac{16}{27}$
>
> $C=\dfrac{2}{3}$
>
> $D=\dfrac{9}{13}$

This is a problem of negative binomial $r=2$

$P(X=x)= {x+r-1 \choose r-1}p^rq^x ;\ \ x=0,1,2..$

$P(X\ge5)=1-P(X < 5) \implies 1-(P(X = 0)+P(X = 1)+P(X = 2)+P(X = 3)+P(X = 4))$

This is very time consuming how do I save time on this problem.

How do I utilize [CDF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negative_binomial_distribution) of negative binomial distribution in this problem?

${\displaystyle k\mapsto 1-I_{p}(k+1,\,r),}$ the regularized incomplete beta function

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Another way to think about the question is to observe that if $X \ge 5$, that means that at least $5$ trials are needed to observe the second success.  This is equivalent to saying that no more than $1$ success occurs in the first four trials.

So there are two cases:  $0$ successes in four trials, or exactly $1$ success in $4$ trials.

In the first case, the probability is $(1-p)^4$.  In the second, the probability is $\binom{4}{1} p (1-p)^3$.  So the total probability is $$(1-p)^4 + 4p(1-p)^3$$ where $p = 1/3$.

Comment: Wow what a brilliant way. I feel like dumb. One more thing can we utilize CDF?

Comment: @Daman The CDF is too complicated to utilize : it is better off used for large values as an approximation, but in general is too cumbersome. Do we even know simple values of the reg. incomplete beta function? No, right?

Comment: @Daman :  the answer of Heropup is brillant, but if you want to use the CDF it is not difficult. See my answer

Comment: @heropup Could you please help me with this problem https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3977470/on-the-uniform-convergence-of-the-series-of-the-following-functions , thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Easy is $B:\frac{16}{27}$

$$P(X\geq 5)=1-P(X\leq 4)=1-\binom{2-1}{2-1}\Bigg(\frac{1}{3}\Bigg)^2\cdot\Bigg(\frac{2}{3}\Bigg)^0-\binom{3-1}{2-1}\Bigg(\frac{1}{3}\Bigg)^2\cdot\Bigg(\frac{2}{3}\Bigg)^1-\binom{4-1}{2-1}\Bigg(\frac{1}{3}\Bigg)^2\cdot\Bigg(\frac{2}{3}\Bigg)^2=$$

$$=1-\frac{3}{27}-\frac{4}{27}-\frac{4}{27}=\frac{16}{27}$$

---

Note that there are at least 2 parametrizations of NBinomial. I used the one counting the trials before s successes whose pmf is

$$P(X=n)=\binom{n-1}{s-1}\theta^s(1-\theta)^{n-s}$$

Where the support is $n=s,s+1,s+2,...$

Comment: If we plug in values in ${x+r-1 \choose r-1}p^rq^x$ we get $5$ terms how come you have $3$?

Comment: @Daman see my explanation in the edits

Comment: Oh I see thank you